# Paradox DB: how to change database path programmatically

Tags: c++builder, paradox

I want to change my database path programmatically. I have a folder with several tables, and my users should be able to change from one database to another. For example: active db: D:\app_db\db1 could change to D:\app_db\db2

```
 void change_db(std::string dir)
 { 
  char c[MAX_PATH]={0};  
  TStringList *list= new TStringList();
  list->Clear();
  sprintf(c,"PATH=%s",dir.c_str());
  list->Add(c);
  Session->ModifyAlias(dbalias,list);
  delete list;
  Table1->DatabaseName = dbalias;
}
```

When I run the routine above the tables still contain the old path!

```
Table1->Database->Directory = c;
```

I set the Directory to new Directory, but my application still uses the old tables.

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For simple Paradox access, I recommend you use the`TDatabase` component together with `TTable` or `TQuery`. Don't use aliases.

Set `TDatabase.DatabaseName` to anything you want. You use this name to link `TTable` and `TQuery` components to the TDatabase component. Their corresponding DatabaseName properties should be set to the same name as the `TDatabase` component.

Set `TDatabase.DriverName` to `STANDARD`.

Make sure `TDatabase.Connected` is set to false.

To set the path to the database use the `TDatabase.Params` stringlist.

First clear the list by calling the Clear method on Params, then set the path by calling the Add method.

If you need multiuser access then you also need to set a netdir on the embedded TDatabase session component.

This is what it would look like in Delphi:

```
  MyDatabase.Close;
  MyDatabase.Params.Clear;
  MyDatabase.Params.Add('PATH=' + PathToYourDatabase);
  // NetFileDir can be the same as the database, but I recommend a different folder.
  // Only needed for multiuser access. All users must use the same folder.
  MyDatabase.Session.NetFileDir := PathToYourNetFileDir;
  MyDatabase.Open;
```

You don't need to add a `TSession` component if you only need one connection to the database and only access the database from the main UI thread. TDatabase automatically creates a default session component in the `Session` property.

Comment: thank you, it is complicated to make this using Session. I'll look for another solution.

Comment: You can use a TSession, but it isn't necessary. The above code specifically does not use TSession.